# Move selected string to resource files addon for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I'm looking for visual studio editor addon that move selected string from editor to resource file and replace it with some variable or whatever.

Something like this https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/internationalization.html#Move_Strings_to_Resource_Files feature from resharper extension.

Using resharper is not an option because is to big and to expensive for me atm.

Comment: So, are you looking for open source/free?

Comment: Yes, free/open source, and only that one option...